How to put multiple VMs behind a single *private* IP address on Azure?
I'm working on creating a Blue/Green deployment for a product in Azure but I'm running into a problem regarding outbound traffic to an on-premisses database.
Our initial idea can be seen in this diagram:
You can see the architecture diagram for the blue/green deployment
.
We have three main "moving parts":

A spoke subscription with a VNET and the VMs running different versions of our product

A hub subscription and network with a VPN Gateway

An on-premisses network with a DB and a client


Our production VMs need to be accessible to the on-premisses client at a fixed IP, but also be able to access the DB (which the on-premisses Firewall allows only a single IP).
This worked very nicely with a single VM, but now that we want to do a Blue/Green deployment, things are getting a bit complicated.
The inbound part is very easy with a Load Balancer, but the outbound part (from the server to the on-premisses VM at a fixed private IP) is proving to be way harder than expected. It is specially necessary that the on-premisses network sees a single private IP as the firewall only allows this single IP to access the DB.
I saw a lot of similar questions, but all of them focused on public IP, instead of private IP, which is what I really need.
My initial idea was to use NAT Gateway or Internal Load Balancer with outbound traffic, but they both use public IPs, when we need it to be fully private.
Using Azure Firewall and "forcing" SNAT does translate the IP address, but it uses a pool of internal IPs instead of a fixed one, so that doesn't work either.
Any suggestions?

Resilient, independently tested systems ideally share as few common components as practical. Try to not depend on having an IP address be the same between such environments. Allows more flexibility in case you want to switch around nets or regions or cloud providers.
Duplicate the database to an identical secondary copy. Resulting in one for the blue, and one for the green. Quite a bit more complicated, as now you have to deal with replicating data to the secondary, client load balancing, cut over, and infrastructure cost.  However now you have a disaster recovery copy of the data that's actually tested, and further can deploy DB changes first on a copy with few users.
Although going all in on blue/green assumes the boundary of what separate environments are extends to the database. Could choose DB to remain one shared copy.
Perhaps make the firewall rules workable by adding an additional IP address to the database host.
Then which environment is visible even in the IP destination header. Even if the database happens to be the same instance.

Hi @john-mahowald, thanks for the response! I think one thing that was misleading in my diagram is the "on-premisses network". This is actually a client infrastructure that we connect to, so we sadly have no influence on their network/database structure. They are also very restrict on the number of IPs they allow, so that's why we are going for the "single IP" approach :/
I agree that the ideal would be to have an IP range, but sadly we're limited to this configuration for now
